# Return View Not show in the Layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I'm try to do some page showing in layout page. function running well. but return view not show.
When I'm click button in  main page i need to show next page with some function in controller. Controller things going correct but it is not redirect to next view.

Controller :

```
public ActionResult View(int id = 0)
        {
            User user = db.Users.Find(id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View("View", user);
        }
```

View:

```
@model API.Entities.User

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View";
}

<h2>View</h2>
"Return Values Show here "
```

that controller hit the button click in main page. I use jquery method to track that button click,

JQuery Method:

```
$(function () {
    $('#save').on('click', function () {
        var userID = $("#Agents").val();
        debugger;
        if (userID > 0) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/User/AgentList',
                data: { Id: userID },
                success: function (dataI) {

                }
            });
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }

    });
});
```

please help me.,

Comment: it shows main page. only nothing change

Comment: Here are the thing you need to share - url via which you're going to controller; controller name, location of view and how you set up route tables.

Comment: your question is not clear what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the controller function, you are calling  **View** only so it will display the same name. If you have a page with same name in different controller then you need to specify the entire URL not just the name. if both are in the same controller then there cannot exist multiple views with same name inside one controller

Comment: I use Jquery method as well please see that code again/

Comment: Write the sequence in which the code gets executed...
I think View is hit first then it returns the list to the View page but then when exactly does the ajax call happen?